# AWS database restore

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, sql-server-2014-express

Being a newbie to AWS platform, I am getting the below issue while restoring sql server express backup from S3 bucket on AWS rds:

Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request.
Error making request with Error Code Forbidden and Http Status Code Forbidden. No further error information was returned by the service

One of the things that I have observed in role screen is the warning against GetObjectMetaData under Unrecognized Actions. It can also be found in attached image.

[Attachment - Role screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh772.png)

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting this. I went into the IAM policy a moment ago, and deleted this action from it.

Something seems to be happening now. 150GB to try to restore so won't be a result for a while but that error has gone. Doesn't mean I might not get another one, though ;)